# finding text using regex

Tags: expression

I have string like this `abc+def(ghi)+jkl` and I want to get `{abc,ghi,jkl}` as the result of regex. So far I found: `[a-z]+(?!\\()` but it returns `{abc,de,ghi,jkl}`. Does anyone know how to write proper regular expression? 
Examples:

> var + var_s    => { **var, var_s** }
>
> var + method(arg) + var_s    => { **var, arg, var_s** }
>
> string * string_s + method_name(arg,arg_s)   => { **string, string_s, arg, arg_s** }
>
> var + 2 * ( 3 + something ) +count( 3, gender )   => { **var, something, gender** }

I need to take all strings consist of 'a-z A-z _'  but not ending with `(` char. Strings: `method(, method_name(, count(` should be omitted because of  **(** .

Comment: You don't want `def` in the result?

Comment: You should better explain how the regex should work, e.g. why the string `def` should not be part of the result.

Comment: I'm assuming the missing `def` is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx:

> \b[a-zA-Z_]+(?!\()\b

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/(\w+)/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

(\w+)

Options: case insensitive

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»

Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»

Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»

(regexbuddy is your friend!)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/\b([a-z]+)(?!\(|\))\b/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```